# Not permitted to log in on postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql

After taking base backup, while starting cluster it's given below error

cd /usr/edb/as12/bin

./psql -p 5443 -d postgres -u enterprisedb

psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "enterprisedb" is not permitted to log in

Comment: 1) `psql` is not used to start a cluster, it is a terminal program for connecting to an already running cluster.  2) The error message is self explanatory,  the `enterprisedb` role does not have the `LOGIN` attribute. You will need to use a role that does, for instance `postgres`.

Comment: **Postgresql service is running** using psql for a specific version trying to login, tried for multiple users getting the same issue

Comment: And what the error message says still holds. You need to login with a role that has `LOGIN` attribute.